# Java - Syntax, what does this mean?

Tags: java, syntax

I am currently confused on what this syntax means. If i knew what it was called I would search for it but I saw it in a code and I have no idea what it means.

```
ptr = c < 0 ? ptr.left : ptr.right;
```

It is for traversing through an binary tree.

I am assuming that the first part `c < 0` is a condition, and if its true, then `ptr` becomes `ptr.left`, and if it is false then `ptr` becomes `ptr.right`-

Or is it the other way around? I've never seen this before and would like some clarification. Thanks

Comment: ok thx alot lolloo

Comment: It is called a `ternary operator` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

And, `ptr = c < 0 ? ptr.left : ptr.right;` is same as

`if (c < 0) { ptr = ptr.left } else { ptr = ptr.right };`

Comment: @Isank that documentation is surprisingly wrong: it is *a* ternary operator, but its correct name is the [*conditional operator*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25).

Comment: @AndyTurner - I would like to disagree because as far as I know conditional operators are `&& (AND)` and `|| (OR)`

Comment: @Isank disagree all you like, that's the name in the language spec. If you look at the preceding sections of the spec, the names of the operators you are referring to are the "conditional-and" and "conditional-or" operators.

Comment: @AndyTurner - The same JLS that you posted a link of says this `The ternary conditional operator ? : (§15.25)` too.

Comment: @Isank in that context "ternary" is a qualifying adjective, in the same way that saying "the preceding sections" doesn't mean there's a type of section called a "preceding section".

Comment: I agree with Andy Turner, ternary is just a qualifying adjective for an operator, meaning that it takes exactly three arguments. Similary, `&&` is a binary conditional operator, and `!` is an unary conditional operator.

Comment: PS: The operator in question is also called "Elvis operator" in less formal terms. :)